# Responsive quote carousel using Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to replicate [this Bootsnipp Quote carousel](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/K5VD), that displays:

1. An image on the left
2. Text on the right
3. Dark chevrons that are visible against a white background

It is done using Bootstrap 3, and I want to replicate the look, behaviour, using BS4.

This is my code snippet (using BS 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div style="text-align: left">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
                            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                             laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/pWkk7iiCoDM/400x300" width="200" /></div>
                
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div style="text-align: left">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
                            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                             laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/aob0ukAYfuI/400x300" width="200" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div style="text-align: left">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
                            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                             laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/EUfxH-pze7s/400x300" width="200" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

From my snippet, the text floats to the top of the image - which is **NOT** what I want. I thought I could get the look I wanted, by providing a style that made the `p` display inline - but I thought they might be a more elegant way of doing that.

My question is:

1. How do I get the image to display on left, and the text to display right
2. Use different colored chevrons sothat they are visible against the white background?

Comment: Do you have access to HTML? Can you put images before the text, like on the first slide here? https://jsfiddle.net/yvpxoedh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got your image on the left and text on the right by making the container div be a grid in CSS by adding this code:

```
.carousel-item div{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

I also needed to rearrange the html just so that the image comes before the `p`

And you can change the color of those chevrons by using this code and changing the `fill` to whatever you want the color to be:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='black' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5L4.25 4l2.5-2.5L5.25 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
      
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='black' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5L3.75 4l-2.5 2.5L2.75 8l4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
```

Here's it running:

```css
.carousel-item div{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}


.carousel-control-prev-icon {
   position: absolute;
   left: -50px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='black' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5L4.25 4l2.5-2.5L5.25 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
      
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  position: absolute;
 right: -50px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='black' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5L3.75 4l-2.5 2.5L2.75 8l4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  margin-block-end:  -40px !important;  
}

.carousel-indicators li {
 background-color: black !important;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div style="text-align: left">
                     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/pWkk7iiCoDM/400x300" width="200" />
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
                            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                             laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                       </div>
                
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div style="text-align: left">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/aob0ukAYfuI/400x300" width="200" />
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
                            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                             laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div style="text-align: left">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/EUfxH-pze7s/400x300" width="200" />
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
                            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                             laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </p>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </div>
                                       <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
            </div>  

        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

I've added `position: absolute;` and `left: -50px;` and `right: -50px;` to the left and right chevrons respectively to make it fit better.  As well as added some code in CSS which styles the `.carousel-indicators`